# letters or numbers only in a password with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, numbers, alphanumeric, letters

I found this code for alphanumeric check ("Letters, numbers, spaces or underscores") but I want to change so I will be able to write only letters or numbers. Can anyone tell me how to change this code:

```
function(value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || /^\w+$/i.test(value);}
```

Thanks!

Greg

Comment: Aha, a password weakener. Why not just five radio buttons to select from the preselected passwords "1234", "asdf", "qwerty", "999" and "password"? ;)

Comment: Or, if you thought about it for a moment, you could stop being sarcastic and realise that you have no idea of the context, and that there could be any number of application-specific data items that should be solely alphanumeric.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
function(value, element)
{
    return this.optional(element) || /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/i.test(value);
}
```

EDIT: OK, *no* idea why I can't get that formatting nicely, but the important part is replacing the \w with the character class (the bit in []).

Comment: Four-space indenting for code works a lot better than the back ticks unless you want the code fragment to be inline with your text.

Comment: Oh, and the `i` at the end of the regex means "case insensitive" so you don't need the lower (or upper, if you choose) case letters in the bracket expression -- or you could drop the "insensitive" flag.

Comment: Ach, four-space indenting, that's the puppy! And good point about the case-insensitivity.

Answer (score 0):

I've used this for years now :

http://www.itgroup.com.ph/alphanumeric/

Take a look